# Duda con metodo get() y libreria json en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonobject

estaba probando los diferentes métodos de web scraping en python, y arme lo siguiente:

```
import requests, json, re, pyperclip, sys
url='https://youtu.be/N-V3zqvtbCM?list=RDnOgw9m_n-o4'
# URL Check
def check(url):
    try:
        return requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        print('No estas introduciendo una URL')
        sys.exit()

if __name__== "__main__":
    response=check(url)
    print(response)

    if response.status_code==200:
        print(response.json())
```

pero al ejecutar la ultima linea el terminal me da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Black PC/Proyects/prueba.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(response.json())
  File "C:\Users\Black PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Black PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", 
line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Black PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Black PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: El error es que simplemnte la respuesta no es un JSON.

Comment: Y si quisiera conseguir **url** del archivo en donde esta contenido el vídeo lo podría hacer con requests? O debería usar otro modulo, probé con youtube-dl pero me esta dando errores